# How to loop through the first column of each row of an ag-grid in Protractor?

Tags: angular, protractor, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to test an [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-e2e-test-with-jasmine/) in my Protractor tests.

I'm currently able to loop through each row to verify all columns within the rows below:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    element.all(by.css(`div[row-id="${i}"] div`))            
       .map(function (cell) {
         return cell.getText();
     })
       .then(function (cellValues) {
         expect(cellValues).toEqual(["Toyota", "Celica", "35000"]);
    });
}
```

But instead of verifying each column, I only want to verify the 1st column in each row.

Can someone please tell me what changes I need to make to my code so that I can do this?

Comment: I think all of your problems are from this `.then` syntax. I recommend you to look into `async/await` Promise syntax instead. Your life will become so much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier than you think. Just get all cells from each row, then return just the first one, getText() on that cell, and assert.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  element.all(by.css(`div[row-id="${i}"] div`))
    .first()
    .getText()
    .then(cellText => {
       expect(cellText).toEqual('Something');        
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but when I try to use this I'm getting this error message: Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, div[row-id="0"] div.ag-cell-value)

Comment: Just change the selector back to your original one. Without the `.ag-cell-value` bit. Should work then. I've updated the example in my answer.